# select value of td and download content of selected tds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this table:

```
<table class="results" id="summary_results">
   <tr>
       <td>select all</td>
       <td>name</td>
       <td>id</td>
       <td>address</td>
       <td>url</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>
           <input type="checkbox">
       </td>
       <td>john doe</td>
       <td>1</td>
       <td>33.85 some address</td>
       <td>http://www.domain.com</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox">
       </td>
       <td>jane doe</td>
       <td>2</td>
       <td>34.85 some address</td>
       <td>http://www.domain2.com</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>
           <input type="checkbox">
       </td>
       <td>sam</td>
       <td>3</td>
       <td>33.86 some address</td>
       <td>http://www.domain3.com</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I would like to select all the rows, then download the content of the URLs knowing that each URL is linked to the ID. For example the first url will be `www.domain.com?id=1&report=report`.

ok now I got the select to work but it is taking only the value of the first tr and not the other selected ones.

Comment: function f() {
    var inputs_in_table = document.getElementById("summary_table").getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var i=0; i<inputs_in_table.length; i++) {
        if(inputs_in_table[i].type == "checkbox") inputs_in_table[i].checked= true;
     }
 }

Comment: You won't be able to request URLs that are on a different domain with JavaScript BTW, it violates the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: If he only want to download them, and if their mime types are something that the browser will download, he can create iframes with these url as src attribute. I did it once, it works fairly well.

Comment: so what if I want to download them and then combine them in one pdf file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main issue here is that client-side javascript isn't really the most appropriate method of going about what you seem to be trying to achieve. Parsing the URLs from the table and forming AJAX requests with them isn't in itself hugely tricky, see for example [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6hFpm/). However as noted by wsanville in the comments, there are cross domain restrictions on AJAX that restrict the ability to make calls to arbitrary URLs.

What would be a more feasible method, if you don't want to navigate off the page, is to retrieve the URLs in the method used in the jsfiddle, and then post that list to your own server. Then you will be able to retrieve the URLs data on the server and perform more complicated actions before sending the data back to the user. Something along the lines of:

```
$.ajax({
  url:'/load_urls', //this is assuming you have some routing for the load_urls endpoint
  data:urls, //assuming you have the list of urls in a var called 'urls'
  method:'POST',
  success:function(data){
    //do something with your data
  },
  error:function(err){
    console.log(err); //it broke
  }
```

});

I think overall you should maybe take a step back and re-evaluate exactly what you want to happen, and look at the constraints of the URLs you are going to be retrieving and so on, and then after that if you're still at a loss come back with a more specific question. Good luck!